# What happened in Australia?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, captain-america, captain-america-civil-war

In Captain America: Civil War, when the Avengers meet with the Secretary of State about the after-effects of their previous involvements, or "international incidents", a map is shown with each of these locations, with high impact on the surrounding area. The main ones are NY (Avengers), Washington DC (Winter Soldier), and Sokovia (Age of Ultron).

There are other locations highlighted on the map, one of them being in South East Australia (I'm assuming Sydney). What happened there?

Comment: Well, there are some scenes in *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* that take place in Sydney, but those were low-impact and, y'know, not the Avengers. It's probably just meant to show that the Avengers have been busy.

Comment: The terrigen map in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D shows that Sydney is going to be a hotspot.

Comment: Captain Kangaroo involved maybe?

Comment: Sydney isn't in South Australia which is at the bottom of Australia, it's in New South Wales to the right on the side of Australia. Just an FYI

Comment: The dot in Brazil seems to be between Mato Grosso and Manaus. This is roughly as far away from Rio de Janeiro as Washington DC is from Mexico City.

Comment: btw, that's [Adelaide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelaide)

Comment: @Möoz yes, I'm aware - I'm actually Australian myself :)

Comment: “What happened in Australia?” — Guessing statistically, I suppose a barbecue got _really_ out of control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about this map:

[image]

List of incidents in this map:

- [North America](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/United_States_of_America#Locations)

  - Southern California Coast - I think this is what happened in Iron Man 3.          Including the destruction of Tony Stark's house and his vendetta with Mandarin.
  - San Francisco - Ant-Man incidents.
  - Washington D.C - Captain America: The Winter Soldier
- [South America](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Rio_de_Janeiro)

  - Rio de Janeiro - The Incredible Hulk.
- [Eastern Europe](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Sokovia)

  - Sokovia - Avengers: Age of Ultron.
- [Africa](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Africa)

  - Can't remember what happened in Egypt. This might be a reference to X-Men: Apocalypse. Since there are differences between two universes, I think that's a long shot. If we are going for the MCU references, I can point to *Project Insight* that was mentioned in Captain America: The Winter Soldier. Egypt was one of the intended targets because some of its citizens were deemed a threat for HYDRA's plans.
  - Lagos - Captain America: Civil War. The fight among Avengers and Crossbones casued casualties.
- [China](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/China)

  - I'm not sure but it might be relevant with Iron Man 3 incident where the Chinese Theater was destroyed by Aldrich Killian. But this is not an incident we can count as "*Incidents Caused by Avengers*."
  - In Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., Centipede Project's side-effects and some of the plot happens to be in China.
- [Australia](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Australia)

  - Couldn't find anything that has a link to MCU, yet there are multiple incidents reference to Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. "*Centipede Warehouse*" was there. One of the S.H.I.E.L.D.'s safehouses was there. Infiltration and ambush of Laura Creek Station happened.

If the map you are talking about is the Terrigen Map that was mentioned in Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D., that's a whole another discussion topic.

You can find a nice discussion about MCU incidents in [here](https://m.reddit.com/r/Marvel/comments/4jmk50/cw_spoilers_can_we_identify_all_these_other/).

Comment: Given the film side of Marvel being so stubborn about acknowledging any of the TV shows, this seems unlikely. Possible, but unlikely.

Comment: @phantom42 Unfortunately yes, that is true.

Comment: Just to clarify, yes that's the map I am referring to. And so far the AoS is the only explanation anyone has come up with so far

Comment: Just to let you know. The mark on the map in South Australia is of the state capital Adelaide. Sydney is on the East Coast.

Comment: The Chinese Theatre is in Hollywood, not China. LMAO.

Comment: The spot in South America is nowhere near Rio. If that's supposed to be Rio, then the spot in southern California could be representing something anywhere between Seattle and Dallas.

Comment: Most of those incidents you mention had nothing to do with the Avengers: they weren't involved in the events of Iron Man 3, The incredible Hulk happened well beforehand, they weren't involved with Ant-Man (and that wasn't a major incident anyway), and they weren't involved with The Winter Soldier, which was a SHIELD and US government problem. Age of Ultron implies the Avengers have been hopping around the world doing things prior to the film (note that Natasha has worked out how to deal with the Hulk already), so some of those dots may simply be stuff that wasn't seen in a film.

Comment: The location also corresponds to a large Uranium deposit in South Australia. Easy to imagine an incident about this.